# Question on Conditionals

Tags: shell, sh

How can I write a POSIX shell script that does two things:

1) When $var1 OR $var2 is defined AND non-null, echo "success"
2) When $var3 is defined with anything, echo "success2"

I tried many combinations of the -ne -z and -a operators but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I tested the following in a Bash shell in POSIX mode - I am not absolutely certain that all of it is strictly POSIX)

```
$ var1=
$ var2=
$ if [ -n "$var1" -o -n "$var2" ]; then echo "success"; fi
$ var2=1
$ if [ -n "$var1" -o -n "$var2" ]; then echo "success"; fi
success
$ var3=
$ if [ -n "${var3+X}" ]; then echo "success2"; fi
success2
$ unset var3
$ if [ -n "${var3+X}" ]; then echo "success2"; fi
$
```

The first condition `[ -n "$var1" -o -n "$var2" ]` takes advantage of the fact that the not-null requirement also implies that the variable are set.

The second case is trickier. `"${var3+X}"` [expands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to nothing if `var3` is unset and to `X` if it is set. That way you can tell unset and null variables apart.

Comment: Thanks. I neglected the quotes around the variable invocations which appears to yield discrepant results.